# Excel - assistance in identifying records with the same answer in two columns

Tags: excel

In Excel - i have 2 columns, Column A with 'yes/no' and Column B with a 'yes/no'.
I need to be able to identify which records have a 'yes' in both Column A and B.
How do I go about that?

Answer (score 0):

In column C you can use:

```
=AND(A1="Yes", B1="Yes")
```

That will return a TRUE or a FALSE. You could then use that in an IF statement:

```
=IF(AND(A1="Yes", B1="Yes"), "They're both Yes", "They are not both Yes :(")
```